# How do I Override pagination links generated by active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari, active-model-serializers, json-api

I want to override the Pagination links generated by the `active_model_serializers` in association with `kaminari`. How do I achieve this, there is no information on [this page](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md) about overriding
[image]

Moreover, the links generated are in this order>> {"self", "first", "prev", "next", "last"}

I want them to be in this order instead>> {"first", "prev", "self", "next", "last"}

Below is the snippet of index method from admins controller:

```
  def index
    @search = Admin.search(params[:q])
    if params[:page]
      @admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(params[:page][:number])
    else
      @admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(1)
    end
    @admins_json = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins)
    @admins_json = @admins_json.to_json(serialization_context: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializationContext.new(request))
    @page_entries_info = view_context.page_entries_info @admins
    # render json: @admins
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json { render :json => @admins, meta: {:page_entries_info => @page_entries_info} }
    end
  end
```

Comment: how are you rendering your links?

Comment: updated the question with the code snippet

Comment: ok, that's how you're rendering the JSON to send to your front end, cool. for clarification, is Kaminari reading the meta attribute on its own? or are you telling it how to read the meta attribute?

Also, for `view_context.page_entries_info`, does that contain the 'normal' Kaminari links without AMS?

Comment: it looks like you may be interested in https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#customizing-the-pagination-helper

Comment: `view_context.page_entries_info` contains the following text, and it has got nothing to do with the AMS: `Displaying users 1 - 10 of 49 in total`

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli please help!

Comment: Can I extend json_api adapter and override the pagination method to generate my own pagination links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the file pagination_links.rb

Copy the contents of `/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/bundler/gems/active_model_serializers-afe3c938070d/lib/active_model_serializers/adapter/json_api/pagination_links.rb` into `#lib/active_model_serializers/adapter/json_api/pagination_links.rb` and do whatever you want.